# Poi how to change cell type after changing style

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Im editing an xlsx file and Im trying to find some mistakes in numerical cells and make the bold. 
the numbers are big for instance: 13882004729568

After finding them and changing the font to bold (or changing foreground color) the cell type is changing to its default state and I get : b1.3882E+13
even after trying to change the type to numerical.

```
XSSFFont italic = wb.createFont();
italic.setFontName("Arial");
italic.setItalic(true);
CellStyle italicStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
italicStyle.setFont(italic);
cell.setCellStyle(italicStyle);
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
Is it other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

@maraca thx for the help
what I did is :

```
XSSFDataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
italicStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("##0"));
```

so the format change made the difference

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation of `setCellType` ([link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType%28int%29)):

> Set the cells type (numeric, formula or string).
>   If the cell currently contains a value, the value will be converted to match the new type, if possible. Formatting is generally lost in the process however.

So, just switch the statements and it should work:

```
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellStyle(italicStyle);
```

Another possibility is that you run out of styles, because you create a new one each time. Create the style once and reuse it.

You can either get the style before changing the cell type or you have to set the format too:

```
italicStyle.setDataFormat(wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("0"));
```

(Just to show the priciple, don't create a new data format each time, reuse.)

Comment: Tried it but it remains the same

Comment: @GurmanEduard then you might set cell type again with another function or later? I don't see a problem in the code displayed, Excel can have really annoying limitations (the number of styles is limited!), but POI itself was always reliable in all the projects I used it.

Comment: Ive changed the style only once for each cell with error, also tried the cetCellType method in different locations. I cant find any other way to change the cells type.

Comment: @GurmanEduard you need to set the data format too it seems (unless you get the style before changing the type).